# Find all parents where all child record matches exactly from given list in has many through association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following relationship

```
class Invoice
  has_many :entries
  has_many :price_matrixes, through: entries
end

class Entry
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :price_matrix
end

class PriceMatrix
  has_many :entries
  has_many :invoices, through: entries
end
```

Now, I have a set of price_matrix ids, for example [1, 2] and, I want to find all invoices that have EXACTLY this two price matrix only.

Note: Tried this `Invoice.includes(:price_matrixes).where(price_matrixes: {id: [1, 2]})` but this is supposed to return record even if one of the ids from list will match.

Comment: Which database do you use, Postgres, MySQL, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be solved easily with plain SQL. Assuming you use PostgreSQL 9+, this is SQL-query to fetch invoice ids which match your condition (have EXACTLY price matrixes with ids [1, 2] only):

```
SELECT I.id
FROM invoices I  
  JOIN entries E ON E.invoice_id = I.id
GROUP BY I.id
HAVING array_agg(E.price_matrix_id ORDER BY E.price_matrix_id ASC) = ARRAY[1,2];
```

Here we join `invoices` and `entries`, group results by `invoice.id`, and filter only those ones which have given `price_matrix_ids`. Please note that `ARRAY[1,2]` expression should contain `price_matrix_ids` sorted in ascending order.

Online demo: http://rextester.com/TAEUU9220

Back to Ruby, here is the code:

```
price_matrix_ids = [1,2].sort

Invoice.joins(:entries).having("array_agg(entries.price_matrix_id ORDER BY entries.price_matrix_id ASC) = ARRAY[#{price_matrix_ids.join(',')}]").group('invoices.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails >= 3.2

```
Invoice.includes(:price_matrix).where(price_matrix: {id: [1, 2]})
```

Rails < 3.2

```
Invoice.joins(:price_matrix).where("price_matrix.id IN [1, 2]")
```

Comment: This will give invoices even if one of the ids will match.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `inner join` and the same `where clause` you tried.

```
Invoice
  .joins('INNER JOIN entries on entries.invoice_id = invoices.id')
  .where(entries: { price_matrix_id: [1, 2] })
```

Comment: This query will return invoices which can have one of these price_matrix_ids from the list. Also it can have duplicates.

Comment: You can improve the SQL to not return the duplicated one. This query returns what he wanted.